# Selenium seems to ignore timeout period and timeout message in driver.wait()

Tags: javascript, selenium, asynchronous, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I'm having trouble getting custom error messages to work with `driver.wait()` in selenium (+ cucumber).  The definition is `driver.wait(condition, timeout, message)` where

- condition is something like `until.elementLocated(By.css('.myClass'))`
- timeout is in ms
- message is "An optional message to use if the wait times out."

More info [here](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/index_exports_ThenableWebDriver.html) under `this.wait()`.

As far as I understand it, the point of the api is that you can pass a timeout period and a message to use if the timeout period expires without the condition being true.

With that in mind, I defined a function `locateElementWithTimeout` that takes

- the driver
- a locator (something like `By.css(".myClass")`)
- a timeout value (something like `5000`)
- a timeoutMessage (something like "my timeout message")

```
async function locateElementWithTimeout(driver, by, timeout, timeoutMessage) {
  // need to split into 2 as we use timeout twice
  const timeoutInHalf = Math.floor(timeout / 2); 

  const element = await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(by), timeoutInHalf, timeoutMessage);
  await driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(element), timeoutInHalf, timeoutMessage);
  return element;
}
```

And I also defined a function `typeInWithTimeout`

```
async function typeInWithTimeout(driver, by, timeout, timeoutMessage, textToType) {
  const element = await locateElementWithTimeout(driver, by, timeout,
    `Unable to locate element for typing text - ${timeoutMessage}`);

  // bridge is needed for anything apart from firefox
  const actions = driver.actions({ bridge: true });
  await actions.click(element).sendKeys(textToType).perform();
}
```

called like

```
await typeInWithTimeout(driver, By.id("login_box"), 5000, 'Unable to locate login box', "myUsername");
```

Previously in my code (~1 second of execution earlier) I called the following function to define timeouts:

```
await driver.manage().setTimeouts({
  implicit: 50 * 1000,
  pageLoad: 50 * 1000,
  script: 50 * 1000,
});
```

So now to my problem. I'm testing the failure condition by trying to locate an element that doesn't exist, with the expectation that it throws an error with the `message` that I defined.  My problem is that instead of waiting the 5 seconds that I requested in the function call, selenium instead waits for the full 50 seconds and then fails with `Error: function timed out, ensure the promise resolves within 50000 milliseconds`.  Why doesn't it fail in the 5 seconds that I requested?

Comment: because of implicit wait... don't set that.

Comment: @pcalkins so should I set it to 0 before attempting these calls?

Comment: The answer is yes. yes - I should set implicit wait to 0 before attempting the calls.  In fact, don't even bother implicitly waiting in your tests.. for some reason they take precedence over explicit waits

Comment: yep, implicit waits are global and should not be mixed with explicit waits.

Comment: you can probably skip the whole driver.manage().setTimeouts part here.  The drivers have their own default values for pageLoad and script.